# insert string between each pair of doublequotes

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am stuck with situation, I have string as shown below:

```
-name "B_12*" -o -name "B_21*" -o -name "B_31" -o -name "B_41"
```

My requirement is I want to convert above string is as shown below:

```
-name "B_12*.tar" -o -name "B_21*.tar" -o -name "B_31.tar" -o -name "B_41.tar"
```

I am not expert with bash commands but I have little bit idea the problem could be solved with `sed` command.

Comment: You should add more details on what exactly needs to be replaced. Is it always `-name "B_XX*"` or something else?

Comment: Show us what you have tried and the problem it has.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to construct a list of arguments (for the `find` command?) as a string. This is almost always the wrong way to do it. The usual way to do it right is with an array instead of a plain string (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quotes-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-variables)).

Answer (score 3):

The only tricky part here is that you need to match both quotes so that they won't be matched again. With a sed distro which has ERE support by -E option, following command would suffice.

```
sed -E 's/("[^"]*)"/\1.tar"/g' file
```

Comment: Hello, it seems that the query is always done in sed. It is convenient!

Comment: I keep thinking that I have to make a query (such as a loop to do this). thanks!

Comment: The `g` af the end of the regex tells sed to loop over all the occurences that have to be changed.

Comment: @Pierre correct. except that it's not a part of *regex* but *flag* part of the *sed script*; misuse of terminology often leads to confusion

Comment: @oguzismail: Of course, I mean *after the regex*, better than *at the end of the regex*.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer.. What would be regex if i want to search only files having number before the extension example: B_12.csv, B_22.csv and B_22-UK.csv I want regex whic should get me B_12.cvs and B_22.csv and should exlcude B_22-UK.csv

Comment: @Qasim That's a separate question

Answer (score 1):

This pattern will match the text string without single quote , all you need to do is get all the matches and perform an alternate query to add `.tar`

```
\b[A-Z][^"]+
```

[image]

- `\b[A-Z]` match a Char in scope [A-Z]
- `[^"]` match until "

  Demo [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/t0AGQg/2)

  [sed-replace-syntax](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-sed-to-find-and-replace-string-in-files/)

Comment: I order to have the same results as regex101.com, I think you need to add the `-E` flag to the *sed* command.

Comment: Even with -E some seds will not recognize `\b`

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer..
What would be regex if i want to search only files having number before the extension
example:
B_12.csv, B_22.csv and B_22-UK.csv
I want regex whic  should get me B_12.cvs and B_22.csv 
and should exlcude B_22-UK.csv